# Restricting the number of threads in Oio Netty server

Tags: java, io, netty

I'm trying to use Oio in my Server Netty-based application. I\m currently using it as follows:

```
String host: String = //...
int port = //...

ServerBootstrap server = new ServerBootstrap()
  .group(new OioEventLoopGroup(), new OioEventLoopGroup())
  .localAddress(new InetSocketAddress(host, port))
    .channel(OioServerSocketChannel.class)
    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {
      public void initChannel(Channel ch){
         ch.pipeline()
        //adding handlers
      }
    })
server.bind().sync()
```

The thing is the number of threads will grow without any bounds. But I want to restrict it to, say 64. If more than 64 clients will try to connect I want to do something (probably respond with connection refused)

Is there a way to control the number of threads in Netty Oio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try creating the OioEventGroup with a limit i.e. use either of the below constructors
`public OioEventLoopGroup(int maxChannels)`
or

```
public OioEventLoopGroup(int maxChannels,
                         java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory threadFactory)
```

[Link](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/oio/OioEventLoopGroup.html#OioEventLoopGroup-int-) to the documentation.

Currently, you are creating it with no limit, so threads are growing without any bound.